# Добавление строки через парсинг вверх экрана UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Столкнулся проблемой данный ряд при парсинге появляется внизу , а не вверху .Уже перепробовал много методов подбора.Вот мой код....
вот мой код Рефрешь.

```
@objc func refreshing() {


        loadObjects1()
        loadObjects2()
        loadObjects3()


        tableView.reloadData()

        refresh.endRefreshing()

    }
```

функция для загрузки вверх строки :

я эту функцию использую во viewDidLoad и Рефреше

```
 func insertNewRow() {
            soccerString.insert(Soccer(), at: 0)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .automatic)

        }
```

в Интернете нашел статью если есть beginUpdates и endUpdates , то reloadData не используется.Уже все варианты испоьзовал.Даже в функцию Парсе вставлял . 
вот код:

```
 func loadObjects3() {
        let query = Tennis.query() as! PFQuery<Tennis>


        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.tennisString.removeAll()

                self.tennisString = objects!
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }

        }
    }
```

Может кто то сталкивался с проблемой и подскажите... ? подскажите предложения